# Update Value on Multi-dimensional Array?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I would like to update destinos.origenes.base_price based on destinos.ciudad_id and destinos_origenes.ciudad_id, so far this is what I am been doing witouth success:

```
        //
        $updateResult2 = $coll_rutas->updateOne(

           /* CONDITION */
            [
                "_id" => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($ruta_id),
                "destinos.ciudad_id" => 1, // for morelia, mich
                "destinos.origenes.ciudad_id" => 122 // for selma, ca
            ],

            /* update */
            [
                '$set' => [
                    'destinos.$[].origenes.$[].base_price' => $destino_origen_amount
                ]
            ]

        );
```

**This is the mongo object:**

```
{
    "id": "5e27ee3e09558a0570003132",
    "nombre": "THE RUTA"    
    "clave": "TR",
    "descripcion": null,
    "active": true,
    "destinos": [
        {
            "ciudad_id": "1",
            "nombre_destino": "Morelia, Mich",
            "orden": "1",
            "notas": null,
            "origenes": [
                {
                    "ciudad_id": "12",
                    "nombre_origen": "Tlaltenango, Zac",
                    "orden": "1",
                    "notas": null,
                    "base_price": "666.66"
                },
                {
                    "ciudad_id": "30",
                    "nombre_origen": "Camargo, Chih",
                    "orden": "2",
                    "notas": null,
                    "base_price": "666.66"
                },
                {
                    "ciudad_id": "122",
                    "nombre_origen": "Selma, Ca",
                    "orden": "3",
                    "notas": null,
                    "base_price": "666.66"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ciudad_id": "2",
            "nombre_destino": "Zamora, Mich",
            "orden": "2",
            "notas": null,
            "origenes": [
                {
                    "ciudad_id": "12",
                    "nombre_origen": "Tlaltenango, Zac",
                    "orden": "1",
                    "notas": null,
                    "base_price": "666.66"
                },
                {
                    "ciudad_id": "30",
                    "nombre_origen": "Camargo, Chih",
                    "orden": "2",
                    "notas": null,
                    "base_price": "666.66"
                },
                {
                    "ciudad_id": "122",
                    "nombre_origen": "Selma, Ca",
                    "orden": "3",
                    "notas": null,
                    "base_price": "666.66"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, the new base_price is the same for all elements in origenes? We can write in spanish if you want :p

Comment: Please keep in English as others may be able to help, but this is limited if they cannot understand the extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `arrayFilters` works fine, I tested with your object example.

```
db.getCollection('temp').update({}, {
    $set: {
      "destinos.$[d].origenes.$[o].base_price":450
    },
    }, { 
      arrayFilters: [
        {
           "d.ciudad_id": "1",
        },
        {
           "o.ciudad_id": "122"
        }
      ]
})
```

[image]

[image]

And check this: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mongodb-driver-bulkwrite.update.php because `arrayFilter` is an element in the options.

```
[
    "_id" => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($ruta_id)
],
[
    '$set' => [
        "destinos.$[d].origenes.$[o].base_price" => 450
    ]
],
[
    "arrayFilters" => 
    [
        ["d.ciudad_id" => "1"],["o.ciudad_id" => "122"]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Invalid key 'arrayFilters': update only works with $ operators

Comment: //
        $updateResult2 = $coll_rutas->updateOne(

            /* CONDITION */
            [
                "_id" => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($ruta_id)
            ],

            /* DO THE FOLLOWING */
            [
                '$set' => [
                    'destinos.$[d].origenes.$[o].base_price' => $destino_origen_amount
                ],
                'arrayFilters' => [
                    'd.ciudad_id' => $destino_ciudad_id,
                    'o.ciudad_id' => $destino_origen_ciudad_id,
                ]
            ]

        );

Comment: Try to move the arrayFilters to 3º parameter

Comment: I also tried that way and it says "Invalid key '0': update only works with $ operators"

Comment: I got it but know it says this: "arrayFilters" option has invalid keys for a BSON array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507129/php-mongodb-set-using-arrayfilters

Comment: Months ago I worked with PHP and MongoDB and I did a lot of things and I had problems with the arrays as parameters but I don't remember well. But the idea here is the way to resolve your problem because you need to use arrayFilters.

Comment: Try to use arrayFilters with two array like arrayFilters => [[cond1],[cond2]]

Comment: Maximiliano That was it!!